# Error when using [Authorize]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorize

I am getting this error:

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".
```

I only get this error when I put [Authorize] on the home controller.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

To trouble shoot, I have stripped the _layout page of all but this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div class="container body-content">
         @RenderBody()
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Index view for Home is nothing but this:

```
hello world
```

If I remove [Authorize], then there is no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original view has a "Scripts" section declared. You need to either remove that or add this code to your layour page:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: It's weird that the `[Authorize]` attribute affects this, unless there's something I'm missing.

Comment: It shouldn't. I suspect there is another view like /Account/Login rendered first.